# Haskell issues: parse error and empty main

Tags: haskell, io

I have to figure out how to write a Haskell program that does the following:

1. Asks the user for container length, width and height
2. Asks for the maximum allowed mass
3. Calculates and presents the maximum allowed density

After some fooling around with the code and several quality hours studying LearnYouAHaskell, I came to this:

```
main = do
 getLength

isNumber :: String -> Bool
isNumber line = if (null $ filter (`notElem` ['0'..'9'] ++ ['.']) line)
  then True
  else False

getInput :: IO Double
getInput = do
 line <- getLine
 if isNumber line
  then return (read line :: Double)
  else do
  putStrLn "This value is not a number, please try again!"
  getInput

getLength :: IO ()
getLength = do
 putStrLn "-----------------------"
 putStrLn "DensityCalc v1.0"
 putStrLn "-----------------------"
 putStrLn ""
 putStrLn "Please enter the container length to begin."
 putStrLn "Entering 0 will end the program."
 length <- getInput
 if length == 0
  then putStrLn "Goodbye!"
  else do
   putStrLn $ "Length: " ++ show length
   putStrLn "Now enter container width (0 to quit): "
   getWidth length

getWidth :: Double -> IO ()
getWidth length = do
 width <- getInput
 if width == 0
  then putStrLn "Goodbye!"
  else do
   putStrLn $ "Width: " ++ show width
   putStrLn "Now enter container height (0 to quit): "
   getHeight length width

getHeight :: Double -> Double -> IO ()
getHeight length width = do
 height <- getInput
 if height == 0
  then putStrLn "Goodbye!"
  else do
   putStrLn $ "Height: " ++ show height
   putStrLn "Finally, enter maximum allowed mass (0 to quit): "
   getMass length width height   

getMass :: Double -> Double -> Double -> IO ()
getMass length width height = do
 mass <- getInput
 if mass == 0
  then putStrLn "Goodbye!"
  else do
   putStrLn $ "Maximum mass: " ++ show mass
   putStrLn "Calculating density..."
   getDensity length width height mass

getDensity :: Double -> Double -> Double -> Double -> IO ()
getDensity length width height mass = do
 let density = mass * 100.0 / length * width * height
 let roundedDensity = round (density :: Double)
 let shownDensity = (fromIntegral roundedDensity) / 100.0
 putStrLn $ "Maximum allowed freight density: " ++ show shownDensity
 putStrLn "Thank you for using my tool! Goodbye!"
```

My first issue is: when compiling, it's giving me a "parse error on input =" in line 65 -

```
density = mass * 100.0 / length * width * height
```

Second, if I take out the density function altogether, it compiles - but the main function does nothing (returns what I input, and nothing else) - [screenshot](http://content.screencast.com/users/VCibinogins/folders/Jing/media/9849bd48-b8b8-4823-83bc-5182c5e20674/2015-11-24_1049.png)

Where should I look for mistakes?

[edit]

First issue solved, changed the code. Second still present.

[edit2]

It seems that, in order to start, I need to manually type in "getLength" in the Main window. Can I make it call the function immediately?

Comment: In the code. Jokes aside, I suggest you paste the code here instead of linking to parts of it.

Comment: Please don't edit out the mistakes of your original code, it makes the correlation between question and answers very confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `let` to define new bindings inside a `do`.

Comment: Thanks, adding let's to the density bindings solved the first issue. However, the second is still present - I can't make main show any text, it only accepts inputs and mirrors them.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out I need to manually write "getLength" when working with the program to call the function, then everything works fine.

Question is - why do I have to do that, if getLength is explicitly mentioned in the "main = do" clause?

Comment: GHCi does not execute anything by default, just provides a REPL -- you have to call `main` yourself. Otherwise, avoid GHCi and run `runhaskell Yourfile.hs` from the command line, which will execute `main`, but will not give you a REPL as GHCi does.